# How exactly does a .net MVC controller know which View() to return?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

When I want to call a new page in .net, say the "About.cshtml" page, I use the following code in the HomeController:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
    return View();
}
```

To call it I'd use a link to "/Home/About". And if I wanted to create a new page called "Contact.cshtml", for example, I'd copy the above and replace About with Contact.

I know that the route in "/Home" calls the HomeController. But how, exactly, does that controller know to return the About.cshtml page? I assume it's based on the name of the function. But this doesn't sound right to me. About() isn't an HTTP verb like Get() or Post(), and the name of the function normally shouldn't define what it does, unless it already existed.

Also, when exactly is View() defined, and when is it assigned to the About.cshtml page?

Finally, is there an attribute that would allow me to return the About.cshtml page with a different function name (as I can set a function to respond to Get with the [HttpGet] attribute)?

Comment: not that this is exactly how asp/iis goes about it, but it all goes off the url. `example.com/about` gets rewritten internally to `example.com/somescript.asp?page=about`, and from there gets routed around internally to whatever bits of code are necessary to generate/render/output that "about" page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But how, exactly, does that controller know to return the About.cshtml page?

Because the action method name is `About`:

```
public ActionResult About()
```

The route found that method by the URL:

```
/Home/About
```

If the URL didn't include the action:

```
/Home
```

Then it would look for a default action.  Normally this is `Index()`, as configured by the default route mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );
```

Note how a default value is defined for both `controller` and `action` if none is provided on the URL.

> the name of the function normally shouldn't define what it does

Why on Earth not?  A function name *should **exactly*** define what that function does.

---

> Also, when exactly is View() defined

It's in [the base controller class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.aspx).

---

> Finally, is there an attribute that would allow me to return the About.cshtml page with a different function name

Not an attribute per se, but you can specify the view name when calling `View()`:

```
return View("SomeOtherView");
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. What I mean by "a function's name shouldn't define what it does" is, I guess, that it shouldn't *control* what it does. If a function prints the report then a good programmer should certainly call it something like PrintReport(), but calling it that all by itself won't actually make it print the report. But I guess with mvc routes that's how it works, so I should just get used to it!

Comment: @user3557096: Well, with frameworks (like ASP.NET MVC) conventions generally apply.  So there's some give-and-take on the semantics in lieu of the built-in functionality of any framework.  You *can* name your functions whatever you want and explicitly specify the view name when calling `View()`.  With attribute routing (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/) you can also more easily separate the URL endpoint from the method name, if the semantics of them should be different.  (And sometimes they arguably should.)

Answer (score 2):

only to explain a few more (the David's response is so good), **View()** is an object of type **ViewResultBase**, in class **Controller**;

```
protected internal ViewResult View()
{
    return View(viewName: null, masterName: null, model: null);
}
```

ViewResultBase has a method **ExecuteResult()** that receives a parameter of type **ControllerContext** (this parameter has the info about the request) and inside this method, if the name of the view is null, the view name is established based on the url (read the explain of David about the routing) that is called accesing to the RouteData:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    if (context == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
    }
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewName))
    {
        ViewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
    }
    ....
}
```

Here, if you  watch the RouteData you can view that the called action is Index, and this value is set to the ViewName property:

[image]

Regards,